# Not able to write xml with iso encoding to Marklogic via JAVA API

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, marklogic

We are trying to insert an xml with ISO encoding to MarkLogic through JAVA API but gets this error. The xml contains special characters, for example: registered trademark sign  - <h4> ®  </h4>

```
Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-DOCUTF8SEQ: Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence at  line 14145 -- document is not UTF-8 encoded.
```

Code:

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(IP, PORT,
                DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME, PWD, Authentication.DIGEST);
            // acquire the content
            InputStream xmlDocStream = XMLController.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("path to xml file");

            // create a manager for XML documents
            XMLDocumentManager xmlDocMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();

            // create a handle on the content
            InputStreamHandle xmlhandle = new InputStreamHandle(xmlDocStream);

            // write the document content
            xmlDocMgr.write("/" + filename, xmlhandle);
```

Comment: We get the same error if we use mlcp ( marklogic content pump ) for loading this xml

Comment: Yes, and the code is...?

Comment: You already asked basically this but with slightly different wording? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028454/does-marklogic-support-special-characters

Comment: @fge we have added the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

Sravan:

The solution is to specify the current ISO encoding when you read the resource by wrapping the input stream in an InputStreamReader:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-

The Java API converts to UTF-8 when it knows that the content has a different encoding but otherwise assumes that the content is already UTF-8. For more detail about conversion of encoding, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_11208

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I tried using XMLEventReaderHandle and XMLStreamReaderHandle. This has worked fine for the xml file with UTF-8 encoding ie both insertion and retrieval is successful (here Marklogic is converting the special characters to some other form and while retrieving it is displaying the correct form ) but when I have tried the xml with ISO encoding, I'm able to insert but unable to retrieve the special characters in the file.

Comment: MarkLogic always stores JSON, text, and XML documents as UTF-8.  If an application or tool needs to read documents in some other encoding such as  ISO-8859-1, you can use an InputStreamHandle to open an InputStream on the document and then wrap it with a Reader (or other reading API) that specifies the charset for the desired encoding.