# XDMP-DOCUTF8SEQ when trying to store binary content in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

My case is slightly different than the one mentioned in an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027838/not-able-to-write-xml-with-iso-encoding-to-marklogic-via-java-api), I am pushing content that I actually want to just store as binary in MarkLogic. I have code later on in a trigger that will process the content of the file. The content in question is uploaded with a URI that ends in **.txt**.

Using the Java API, I have:

```
    BinaryDocumentManager docManager = binaryClient.newBinaryDocumentManager();
    BinaryWriteHandle handle = new BytesHandle(content).withFormat(Format.BINARY);
```

I hoped that would bypass the UTF-8 requirement. Is my assumption correct?

```
 Server Message: XDMP-DOCUTF8SEQ: Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence at  line 1 -- document is not UTF-8 encoded
```

Comment: Is the content text or binary?

Comment: @MadsHansen the content is actually text, but I am trying to insert is as binary to not get indexed. We actually will process this content and stick it into a separate envelope document. I thought I had done something similar before with MLCP and it's binary flag where some of the content that went in would have been text, but was marked as binary. Would MLCP content be ingested over a different protocol?

Comment: MLCP loads via XCC protocol and does not use the REST API

Comment: If you don’t care about the file suffix, the easiest way to get it loaded as binary would be to use a different file extension. There are other workarounds, but that would be the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java API goes through the REST API, and there is some auto-magic processing that occurs when you invoke [/v1/documents PUT](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/REST/PUT/v1/documents) to insert a document.

If the  URI has a known file extension, then the MIME type mappings to determine the format. When you use a URI with a `.txt` file extension, then it assumes you are loading a text document.

If you were to use a URI that does not end with `.txt` file extension, for instance `.txt.bin`, then it should insert as a `binary()` node.

If you want to insert the document with a `.txt` file extension as a `binary()` node, then you will likely need to insert it differently.

> ## [General Content Type Guidelines](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_49079)
>
> The following guidelines apply to specifying input and output content type for most requests:
>
> - Document content: Rely on the MarkLogic Server MIME type mapping defined for the URI extension.
> - Non-document data: Set the request Content-type and/or Accept headers. In most cases, this means setting the header(s) to `application/xml` or `application/json`.
>
> The installation-wide MarkLogic Server MIME type mappings define associations between MIME type, URI extensions, and document format. For example, the default mappings associate the MIME type `application/pdf`, the 'pdf' URI extension, and the binary document format. You can view, change, and extend the mappings in the 'Mimetypes' section of the Admin Interface or using the XQuery functions [admin:mimetypes-get](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/admin:mimetypes-get) and [admin:mimetypes-add](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/admin:mimetypes-add).